# In Javascript, how to get an element's offsets from its parent, and get also floating values?

Tags: javascript

I'm using js animate() to animate an element from one place to another (with "translate()"), and the initial data (or target's new position) for the animations is being calculated with offsetTop and offsetLeft on page load.

The problem is that both offsetTop and offsetLeft return integers (this is how it should work) while in some cases a target element's **computed** position might be represented as a floating value (125.4px), what gives me back "125" instead.

Therefore, an animated element might stop its animation 1 pixel before the place it was originally intended to be.

Is there any way to get an element's top/left offsets from its parent (not viewport, so "getBoundingClientRect" is not an option), and with floating values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+computed+style+pixel+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of getting offset from parent using `getBoundingClientRect()`:

```js
function getTopOffsetFromParent(element) {
    if(element.parentElement) {
        return element.getBoundingClientRect().top - element.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    }

    return element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
}
```